# Why does wrapping the random method of random.Random seem to affect the RNG?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I tried to log calls to `random()` by putting a wrapper around it to print stuff. Surprisingly I noticed that I started getting different random values. I have created a small example to demonstrate the behavior:

Script main.py:

```
import random

def not_wrapped(seed):
    """ not wrapped """
    gen = random.Random()
    gen.seed(seed)

    # def wrappy(func):
    #     return lambda: func()
    # gen.random = wrappy(gen.random)

    gen.randint(1, 1)
    return gen.getstate()

def wrapped(seed):
    """ wrapped """
    gen = random.Random()
    gen.seed(seed)

    def wrappy(func):
        return lambda: func()
    gen.random = wrappy(gen.random)

    gen.randint(1, 1)
    return gen.getstate()

for s in range(20):
    print(s, not_wrapped(s) == wrapped(s))
```

Output of `python3.7.5 main.py` (same as python 3.6.9)

```
0 True
1 False
2 False
3 False
4 False
5 True
6 False
7 False
8 False
9 False
10 True
11 False
12 False
13 False
14 False
15 True
16 False
17 True
18 False
19 True
```

So as you see the state of the Random instance `gen` is different and it depends on if I wrap gen.random in `wrappy` or not.

If I call `randint()` twice the test will fail for all seeds 0-19. For Python 2.7.17 the `wrapped` and `not_wrapped` functions returns the same random value every time (prints True for every seed).

Does anyone know what is going on?

Python 3.6 online example: http://tpcg.io/inbKc8hK

On Python 3.8.2 on this online repl, the problem does **not** show: https://repl.it/@DavidMoberg/ExemplaryTeemingDos

(This question has been cross posted at: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/i597at/is_there_a_bug_in_randomrandom/)

Comment: It looks like you are comparing the output of `getstate()` instead of actual random output. Is see nothing in the docs that says `getstate()` should be examined. The output of `getstate()` is only useful as the input to a `setstate()` call. For example, it may contains fields that aren't actually used in your case but are set nevertheless for convenience, e.g. the time of the day. I don't actually know what's happening under the hood.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I don't think it contains anything like that. Anyway replacing `getstate` with a call to `random` yields the same output.

Comment: So it's fixed in a newer version? What are you worried about then?

Comment: @AlexWeavers I'm not necessarily worried, I want to know why it happens - it's interesting don't you think? If no one knows, it might be a big that's still there or that might reappear. Also not everyone runs the latest python version. At my office we are on python 3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is about Python 3.6.

The state is only changed by the `gen.randint(1, 1)` call, so let's see what it calls under the hood.

1. [Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f02de961b9f19a5db0ead56305fe0057a78787ae/Lib/random.py#L217) is the implementation of `random.Random.randint`:

   ```
   def randint(self, a, b):
       """Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
       """

       return self.randrange(a, b+1)
   ```
2. `random.Random.randrange` is [right above](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f02de961b9f19a5db0ead56305fe0057a78787ae/Lib/random.py#L173), and it generates random numbers using `random.Random._randbelow`...
3. ...which is implemented [right below `randint`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f02de961b9f19a5db0ead56305fe0057a78787ae/Lib/random.py#L223), and *checks whether the `random` method has been overridden!*

Looks like `_randbelow` is the issue:

```
...
from types import MethodType as _MethodType, BuiltinMethodType as _BuiltinMethodType
...


def _randbelow(self, n, int=int, maxsize=1<<BPF, type=type,
               Method=_MethodType, BuiltinMethod=_BuiltinMethodType):
    "Return a random int in the range [0,n).  Raises ValueError if n==0."

    random = self.random
    getrandbits = self.getrandbits

    # CHECKS IF random HAS BEEN OVERRIDDEN!

    # If not, this is the default behaviour:

    # Only call self.getrandbits if the original random() builtin method
    # has not been overridden or if a new getrandbits() was supplied.
    if type(random) is BuiltinMethod or type(getrandbits) is Method:
        k = n.bit_length()  # don't use (n-1) here because n can be 1
        r = getrandbits(k)          # 0 <= r < 2**k
        while r >= n:
            r = getrandbits(k)
        return r

    # OTHERWISE, it does something different!

    # There's an overridden random() method but no new getrandbits() method,
    # so we can only use random() from here.

    # And then it goes on to use `random` only, no `getrandbits`!
```

(For reference, `getrandbits` is implemented in C [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46e19b61d31ba99f049258efa4ff1334856a3643/Modules/_randommodule.c#L467), and `random` is also implemented in C [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/46e19b61d31ba99f049258efa4ff1334856a3643/Modules/_randommodule.c#L169).)

So there's the difference: the `randint` method ends up behaving differently depending on whether `random` has been overridden or not.